# How to remove title bar in Blender 2.8 Beta?

Tags: interface

How do i remove the tittle bar for blender 2.8?

[image]

In blender2.79 I'm using the hot key <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>

It does not work for Blender 2.8 beta.

Answer (score 4):

In the top menu: Window->Toggle Window Fullscreen

Or use:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>

To toggle full screen use:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>

To see the shortcuts that changed in 2.8 go to:

https://developer.blender.org/T55194

Comment: Is there a way to do it without going full screen? I have a fairly large monitor and don't want blender to take up the whole space, but I also would prefer to not have the title bar visible.